# post a mysql data from controller to view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to send from a controller to a view an array of all contacts who are in my database table "Contacts" and then display them on a drop down menu.I followed the CodeIgniter documentation about this topic http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html but it isn't really what I would like to do.
Here is what I tried to do :

```
function getAll_contact(){
     $exist= $this->contacts_model->get_all('contacts');
     if($exist)
        {
            $all_contact = $this->contacts_model->read('contacts');
        //echo json_encode($all_contact); prints all the contacts in the table
                    $this->load->view('myView', $contact);
        }
    }
```

In my view :

```
      <select class="span4">
          <?php if(isset($all_contact) && ! empty($all_contact)){ 
            foreach($all_contact as $contact){
            echo "<option value='".$contact->id_contact."'>".$contact->company."</option>";


    }
}
      </select>
```

This does not show anything on the drop down menu. Could anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

put ur result into data array..

```
$data['all_contact']=$this->contacts_model->read('contacts');
```

and send the array to view

```
$this->load->view('myView', $data);
```

and you can take that variable in your view with $all_contact ..like u currently have..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you've named the variable $contact instead of $all_contact.

The solution:

```
function getAll_contact(){
  $exist= $this->contacts_model->get_all('contacts');
  if($exist)
  {
    $data['all_contact'] = $this->contacts_model->read('contacts');
    //echo json_encode($data); prints all the contacts in the table
    $this->load->view('myView', $data);
  }
}
```

Then you access it like you are currently in your view.